# transmission of data between components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events, rxjs

Component A has 2 components inside:

```
    <div class="classStyleLeft">
        <app-picture [IdSectionPicture]="2" [PData]="modelPage"></app-picture>          
    </div>
    <div class="classStyleRight">     
        <app-list [IdSectionList]="2" [PData]="modelPage"></app-list>
    </div>
```

In the component `app-list`, select an item from the list and click the method `showInfo`:

```
    <ul *ngFor="let value of PData.content[IdSectionList].content; let valueIndex = index;">
      <li (click)="showInfo(IdSectionList, valueIndex)">
        <b>{{value.value}}</b>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I want the method parameters `showInfo` they were transferred to the component `app-picture`. Component content `app-picture`:

```
<div>{{PData.content[IdSectionList].value[valueIndex].value}}</div>
```

I do not know how to do it.

I would ask for help.
Thank you

Comment: You can use service to share data as @Shashank Vivek has explained in answer and if by any chance service is not helpful for you so you can use `EventEmitter` @Output

Comment: @skdroid : They are not `Parent` child component so they cant use EventEmitter. They are sibling components so they have to use `Observables`

Comment: @ShashankVivek : yes, they are not parent-child, and for EventEmitter the parent component is required and I was referring/assuming the parent where the app-list, app-picture components are consuming.

Comment: you can use `EventEmitter`. On clicking the `showInfo` in `app-list`, emit a event to the parent and update the variables passed to `app-picture ` The input variables are always listened to, so the changes will be reflected in the `app-picture` component.

Comment: @EeshwarAnkathi : Not a standard practice as per the Angular guidelines. To correct your approach, you should also mention about `ngOnChange` where you'll have to track changes in `@Input` param. Its not a good practice to do things just for the sake of doing it.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the data using service won't be enough as they events has to be listened to.
Since it is a sibling component, create a service with `BehaviorSubject` as:

```
export class InfoService{
   private infoSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({id: '',value: ''});

   showInfoEventEmitter(data){
     this.infoSubject.next(data);
   }

   showInfoEventListener(){
     return this.infoSubject.asObservable();
   }

}
```

and then use it in component as

**app-list.component**

```
constructor(public infoSvc: InfoService){}

showInfo(IdSectionList, valueIndex){
   this.infoSvc.showInfoEventEmitter({id:IdSectionList, value:  valueIndex})
}
```

and in **app-picture.component**

```
eventSubscription: Subscription;
constructor(public infoSvc: InfoService){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.eventSubscription = this.infoSvc.showInfoEventListener().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res); // you have the event here
   })
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.eventSubscription.unsubscribe(); // to stop listening to this event after component is destroyed
}
```

Comment: in the app-picture component,   the methods `showInfoEventListener` not see `subscribe` return ERROR: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: @609tom : My bad. I missed `return` in that function. Please check now.

Comment: I would like to ask for help. an error message appears in the console: this.infoService.showInfoEventListener(...).subscribe is not a function . The method is in the `app-picture` component

Comment: @609tom : I have added `return` statement in `showInfoEventListener` of `InfoService` now. Please check my updated code

Comment: works, but I still have a small error in console: property 'value' does not exist on type 'object'. I  do not know how to do it. I would ask for help. Thank you

Comment: method `ngOnInit` returns nothing  (initialisation the first time)

Comment: @609tom : On which line are you getting this error `console: property 'value' does not exist on type 'object'.`

Comment: in the line: `return this.Idvalue = res.value`

Comment: `ngOnInit(){
    this.eventSubscription = this.infoService.showInfoEventListener()
      .subscribe(res => {
        return this.IdValue = res.value;
      } );}`

Comment: You can help me?

Comment: @609tom : Try `private infoSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({id: '',value: ''});`. I have updated the same in the code as well.  Basically,  `BehaviorSubject<any>({});` was emitting an empty `object` with no `value` . So I initialized it . Let me know if it helped

Comment: @609tom : can it be marked as selected answer ? it would help others as well